# how do I reverse rails g controller some_namespace::some_controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to remove a namespaced controller in command line, how can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rails destroy controller some_namespace::some_controller
```

I just ran it on my system, here is the output:

```
 rails destroy controller my::items
      remove  app/controllers/my/items_controller.rb
      remove    app/views/my/items
      invoke  helper
      remove    app/helpers/my/items_helper.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

use destroy:

```
rails destroy some_controller options etc..
```